# Вывести атрибут экземпляра класса, в зависимости от выбора в Combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, tkinter, gui

Как вывести значение атрибута экземпляра класса в зависимости от выбора экземпляра в интерфейсе программы?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
tk = Tk()

spisok = ttk.Combobox(tk, values=(["Right", "Left"]))
spisok.current(0)

znachenie1 = Label(tk, text='<>')

def go(self):

    class Bet:
        def __init__(self, name, variant):
            self.name = name
            self.variant = variant

    Right = Bet("Right", variant="1")
    Left = Bet("Left", variant="2")

    znachenie1.config(text="variant в зависимости от выбора экземпляра из spisok")

spisok.grid(row=1, column=0)

znachenie1.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn1 = Button(text="Расчет")
btn1.bind("<Button-1>", go)
btn1.grid(row=4, column=2)

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант вы можете создать список виджетов:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
tk = Tk()

spisok = ttk.Combobox(tk, values=(["Right", "Left"]))
spisok.current(0)

znachenie1 = Label(tk, text='<>')

def go(self):

    class Bet:
        def __init__(self, name, variant):
            self.name = name
            self.variant = variant

    Right = Bet("Right", variant="1")
    Left = Bet("Left", variant="2")
    
    _list = [Right, Left]                                                            # +++
    #print(spisok.current())

#    znachenie1.config(text="variant в зависимости от выбора экземпляра из spisok")
    text = f'{_list[spisok.current()].name}: {_list[spisok.current()].variant}'      # +++
    znachenie1.config(text=text)

spisok.grid(row=1, column=0)

znachenie1.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn1 = Button(text="Расчет")
btn1.bind("<Button-1>", go)
btn1.grid(row=4, column=2)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать свой комбобокс, чтобы он хранил сами объекты, а не только их строковое представление, и метод `.get()` возвращал сам выбранный объект:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

tk = Tk()


class MyCombo(ttk.Combobox):
    def __init__(self, *args, values=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, values=values, **kwargs)
        if values is None:
            values = []
        self._values = values
    
    def get(self):
        if self.current() == -1:  # Если ничего не выбрано
            return None
        else:
            return self._values[self.current()]


class Bet:
    def __init__(self, name, variant):
        self.name = name
        self.variant = variant
    
    def __str__(self):
        # Определяем метод __str__ чтобы задать,
        # как объект будет отображаться внутри комбо
        return self.name


Right = Bet("Right", variant="1")
Left = Bet("Left", variant="2")

spisok = MyCombo(tk, values=[Right, Left])
spisok.current(0)

znachenie1 = Label(tk, text='<>')


def go():
    value = spisok.get()  # Получаем выбранный объект из комбо
    znachenie1.config(text=f"{value.name}: {value.variant}")
    # Или znachenie1.config(text=value.variant)
    # если нужно вывести просто значение поля variant выбранного объекта


spisok.grid(row=1, column=0)

znachenie1.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn1 = Button(text="Расчет", command=go)
btn1.grid(row=4, column=2)

tk.mainloop()
```