Как заменить значение на десятичную дробь в combobox
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом могу "спрятать" внутри строки фиксированное значение (десятичная дробь), чтобы при выборе допустим строки "Специалист" ее можно было подставить в итоговую функцию подсчета.
Допустим выбираю в комбобох строку "Специалист", далее допустим ставку и потом подсчет делался исходя из параметров.
Возможно ли в итоговой функции подсчета как то определить функцией параметры в комбобоксе?
Заранее спасибо!
Код не прикладываю, т.к. логику понять и все.



Можно сделать модифицированный комбобокс, как в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1536312/1365. Тогда выбираться будет целый объект, из него получаете нужное поле.
